# Howto change biblatex bibliography style for the label

Tags: macros, biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

How do I change the style of the literature labels in the bibliography?

I'm searching about a few hours now with no luck, so maybe anyone here can help! Below you see my example and at the bottom of the post I show you what I want to get. I read a lot about the `\DeclareFieldFormat` method, but it seems that this one is not working for the labels. I tried it for the book title at this works fine `\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textbf{#1}}`. Isn't there an equivalent for the labels?

Example document file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,
backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{labelname}{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{apple2012staticlibrary}
\cite{fowler2003patterns}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file:

```
@techreport{apple2012staticlibrary,
    Author = {Apple},
    Date-Added = {2013-07-18 07:52:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-07-20 11:39:36 +0000},
    Institution = {Apple Inc.},
    Publisher = {Apple Inc.},
    Title = {Using Static Libraries in iOS},
    Year = {2012}}

@book{fowler2003patterns,
    Address = {Heidelberg, M{\"u}nchen, Landsberg, Frechen, Hamburg},
    Author = {Martin Fowler},
    Date-Added = {2013-07-17 09:26:03 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-07-23 06:49:25 +0000},
    Publisher = {mitp-Verlag},
    Series = {Software-Engineering},
    Title = {Patterns f{\"u}r Enterprise-Application-Architekturen},
    Year = {2003}}
```

This is how it looks like (Ignore the ISBN field. Its just an older screenshot):
[image]

And this is how I want it to look like (with the bold label):

**Apple (2012):** Using Static Libraries in iOS. Techn. Ber. Apple Inc.

**Fowler, Martin (2003):** Patterns für Enterprise-Application-Architekturen. Software-Engineering.
Heidelberg, München, Landsberg, Frechen, Hamburg: mitp-Verlag.

Comment: Does this do what you need: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91570/bibliography-with-biblatex-how-to-achieve-bold-labels-using-the-authoryear-styl

Comment: I knew it wasn't this complicated. ;) Thanks a lot. Don't know why google doesn't show the that post as result...

Comment: Don't worry. It's not always easy to find these things and we're always happy to help out. To keep things neat and tidy, since you got your answer, I'm going to suggest closing this question as an exact duplicate (well written as it was).