# How to make the author field bold, including the conjunction "and" in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

I am using `style = authoryear` in Biblatex and I want to make all author names, including the conjunction "and" in bold. I have used the following commands

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

however this only makes the author names bold but not the "and" conjunction, so I get something like this

[image]

How can I make the "and" and the commas bold in the author field?

Comment: See [Make author names bold in bibliography only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178862/35864) and [Bibliography with biblatex: how to achieve bold labels using the authoryear-style?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91570/35864)

Comment: Seeing that you just copied the approach from the other answer, I would prefer to vote to close as a duplicate of [Make author names bold in bibliography only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178862/35864). WOuld that be OK with you.

Comment: @moewe Yes, it would be ok to flag my question as a duplicate. I have up voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from the following [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178862/make-author-names-bold-in-bibliography-only).

```
\DeclareNameFormat{last-first/first-last-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first/first-last-bold}
```